# Why there are chains hanging from the book shelves in libraries

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

What is the purpose of chains hanging from the book shelves of libraries in the Citadel and Castle Black in *Game of Thrones*?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Definitely a duplicate, the answer on the other question even uses the same paragraph from wikipedia that my answer does.